# undefined reference to : what's wrong?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ld

Im' trying to port a home made software from AIX to "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.8"

I'm facing "undefined reference to" errors at link time and, for now, I can't find where I screwed up.

The goal is to generate an executable from 2 homemade shared librairies (*msi* and *atmi*), some object previously compiled (MsiServices.o) and a C program (pingsrv.c).
Below is the command :

```
gcc -DWall -o bin/pingsrv -DUNIX -I. -g -DUNIX -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -I/home/vgi/git/msi-tools/ping/server/target/msi/include/yaml-cpp -I/home/vgi/git/msi-tools/ping/server/target/msi/include/apr-1 -I/home/vgi/git/msi-tools/ping/server/target/msi/include/activemq-cpp-3.9.4 -I/home/vgi/git/msi-tools/ping/server/target/msi/include /tmp/MsiServices.o ./pingsrv.c -L/home/vgi/git/msi-tools/ping/server/target/msi/lib -lmsi -lactivemq-cpp -llog4cxx -latmi -lapr-1 -laprutil-1 -lexpat -lstdc++ -lyaml-cpp
```

Errors appears a link time:

```
/home/vgi/git/msi-tools/ping/server/target/msi/lib/libatmi.so: undefined reference to `Msi_tpreturn'
/home/vgi/git/msi-tools/ping/server/target/msi/lib/libatmi.so: undefined reference to `Msi_tpcall'
/home/vgi/git/msi-tools/ping/server/target/msi/lib/libmsi.so: undefined reference to `msi::service::optarg'
/home/vgi/git/msi-tools/ping/server/target/msi/lib/libatmi.so: undefined reference to `Msi_userlog'
```

Library atmi is written in C and is able to call some C++ instance methods by using wrappers:

```
...
typedef struct MsiScheduler MsiScheduler ;
extern void Msi_tpreturn(MsiScheduler *,int, long , char *, long, long);
extern void Msi_userlog(MsiScheduler *,char*) ;
extern int Msi_tpcall(MsiScheduler *,char *svc, char *idata, long ilen, char **odata, long *olen, long flags) ;
...
extern void tpreturn(int rval, long rcode, char * data, long len, long flags)
{
    assert(vg_Consumer != NULL) ;
    Msi_tpreturn(vg_Consumer,rval,rcode,data,len,flags) ;
```

}

Wrappers called by this library are defined in another library called *msi*. Wrappers are defined in a C++ source file (MsiScheduler.cpp):

```
void Msi_tpreturn(MsiScheduler * c,int ret,long code,char *data,long len,long flags)
{
    TypedBuffer* buffer = NULL ;

    if (data != NULL)
    {
       buffer = TypedBuffer::createBuffer(getType(data),data,len) ; 
    }
    MsiReply * reply = MsiReply::createReply(ret,code,buffer) ;

    c->tpreturn(reply) ;

    if (data != NULL)
    {
       freebuf(data) ;
    }
    delete reply ;
}
int Msi_tpcall(MsiScheduler * c,char *svc, char *idata, long ilen, char **odata, long *olen, long flags)
{
     ...
}
void Msi_userlog(MsiScheduler *c ,char* str)
{
    c->userlog(str) ;
}
```

header file (MsiScheduler.h) contains this fragment :

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#if defined(__STDC__) || defined(__cplusplus)
extern void Msi_tpreturn(MsiScheduler *,int, long , char *, long, long);
extern void Msi_userlog(MsiScheduler *,char*) ;
extern int Msi_tpcall(MsiScheduler *,char *svc, char *idata, long ilen, char **odata, long *olen, long flags) ;
#else
extern void Msi_tpreturn();
extern void Msi_userlog() ;
extern int Msi_tpcall() ;
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Librairies are constructed like that:

```
g++ -g -fPIC -Wall -I/home/vgi/git/msi/msi-service/target/ext/include/apr-1 -I/home/vgi/git/msi/msi-service/target/ext/include/activemq-cpp-3.9.4 -I/home/vgi/git/msi/msi-service/target/ext/include/yaml-cpp -I/home/vgi/git/msi/msi-service/target/ext/include -I/home/vgi/git/msi/msi-service/target/ext/include -I../lib/inc -I./ -o MsiScheduler.o -c MsiScheduler.cpp
...
g++ -shared MsiUtil.o MsiConfig.o MsiInstrumentation.o MsiMetric.o MsiService.o MsiExceptions.o MsiCharsetConverter.o MsiTypes.o MsiMessage.o MsiMessageUtil.o MsiScheduler.o MsiServer.o -o libmsi.so
...
gcc -g -fPIC -Wall -I/home/vgi/git/msi/msi-service/target/ext/include/apr-1 -I/home/vgi/git/msi/msi-service/target/ext/include/activemq-cpp-3.9.4 -I/home/vgi/git/msi/msi-service/target/ext/include/yaml-cpp -I/home/vgi/git/msi/msi-service/target/ext/include -I/home/vgi/git/msi/msi-service/target/ext/include -I../lib/inc -I./ -o atmi.o -c atmi.c
gcc -shared atmi.o memmngt.o -o libatmi.so
```

FYI, everything compile and link well on AIX OS (with xlc,xlC commands).

I also tried to change librairies order for linking command, without success.

I guess there is something specific to linux/gcc but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: If I understand correct, that the code that calls `Msi_tpreturn` is in `libatmi.so` and the code that provides `Msi_tpreturn` is in `libmsi.so`, you would have to specify `-latmi` before `-lmsi` in your linker command line.

Comment: @Bodo Order usually doesn't matter for shared libraries, only static libraries.

Comment: Please edit to add the output from: `nm -A libmsi.so libatmi.so | grep -E 'Msi_(tpreturn|tpcall|userlog)'`

Comment: Probably not the issue, but: For a program with mixed C and C++, it's generally a good idea to (1) link the final executable with g++ rather than gcc -lstdc++, and (2) define and compile `main` in C++ (if an existing one is written in C, just rename it and have a trivial C++ `main` call that).

Comment: @aschepler below the output of the command :
libmsi.so:0000000000034f20 T _Z10Msi_tpcallPN3msi7service12MsiSchedulerEPcS3_lPS3_Pll
libmsi.so:0000000000035138 T _Z11Msi_userlogPN3msi7service12MsiSchedulerEPc
libmsi.so:0000000000034e55 T _Z12Msi_tpreturnPN3msi7service12MsiSchedulerEilPcll
libatmi.so:                 U Msi_tpcall
libatmi.so:                 U Msi_tpreturn
libatmi.so:                 U Msi_userlog

Comment: You can click the "Edit" link at the bottom of your question.

Comment: @aschepler FYI, MsiServices.cpp contains the main entry, it's a CPP source file created by a template based tool . MsiServices.o is the result of g++ compilation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> libmsi.so:0000000000034f20 T _Z10Msi_tpcallPN3msi7service12MsiSchedulerEPcS3_lPS3_Pll
> libmsi.so:0000000000035138 T _Z11Msi_userlogPN3msi7service12MsiSchedulerEPc
> libmsi.so:0000000000034e55 T _Z12Msi_tpreturnPN3msi7service12MsiSchedulerEilPcll
> libatmi.so: U Msi_tpcall
> libatmi.so: U Msi_tpreturn
> libatmi.so: U Msi_userlog
> ```

In your `nm` output, the `T`'s mean that the symbol on the right is defined in libmsi.so, and the `U`'s mean that the symbol on the right is needed by libatmi.so. But obviously, the names of these symbols don't match up. The names in libmsi.so have the C++ mangling which helps keep overloaded functions separate.

This means the `extern "C"` did not apply to the function definitions when compiling MsiScheduler.cpp. Make sure it includes MsiScheduler.h, and that part of the header is not skipped by any `#if`. If that's not the issue, double check that the function parameter types are exactly the same in the MsiScheduler.h declarations and MsiScheduler.cpp definitions, though they seem to be.

Comment: Thank you @aschelper, I forced `extern "C"` to each function definition and it's works !

Comment: Glad you got farther, but that doesn't explain why the existing header file didn't work.

Comment: indeed, don't know why. Pragma message directive confirmed me that `extern "C"` is correcly triggered inside header file. Strange......

Answer (score 0):

When you're compiling pingsrv.c you try to link msi with -l. Have you put libmsi.so in the library path so that -l can find it?

Comment: Yes I do, all my libraires are located in this directory :  /home/vgi/git/msi-tools/ping/server/target/msi/lib

besides, this is provided to gcc command line : -L/home/vgi/git/msi-tools/ping/server/target/msi/lib -lmsi